# Airflow, Confusion with execution date and timedelta, Will it change based on daylight savings?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a normal parent & child dag dependancy.The child dag monitors for a task to be completed successfully in the parent dag using ExternalTaskSensor. Below is the code for my Child dag's task.

```
start_date = pendulum.datetime(2021, 6, 10, tz="Australia/Melbourne")
dag = DAG ("Child_dag_1", schedule_interval="0 15 * * *", default_args={'owner':'myapp', 'start_date': start_date}, catchup=False, dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440))
parenttask_monitor_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id = "child_task_1",
        external_dag_id = "Parent_dag_1",
        external_task_id = "Parent_task_1",
        allowed_states = ["success"],
        execution_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        dag=dag
    )
```

| Date | Parent dag | Child dag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/03/2023 | Exec_date: 31/03 4:00:00 | Exec_date: 31/03 4:00:00 |
| 1/04/2023 | Exec_date: 01/04 4:00:00 | Exec_date: 01/04 4:00:00 |
| 2/04/2023 | Exec_date: 02/04 5:00:00 | Exec_date: 02/04 5:00:00 |

As you can see from the above data, In the exec_date timefield there has been a 1 hour delay from April 2 onwards. This is because the daylight savings in AEST (Australia) ends on the 2nd of April 3 am. My theory is this 1 hour change messed up the timedelta as the parent dag's previous execution was less than 24 hours now (01/04 4:00:00).
I want to know if my theory is correct or have I misunderstood the concept of exec date?

If my theory is correct, then is there any way or recommendation to avoid such cases?

***Note:** From April 4th, onwards the dags were back to normal without any issues. (3rd April we paused the dags manually)*